# Group MenuItem's Items

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to separate each group within the collection of items in my menuItem by a Separator programmatically.

I know I can use `this.myMenuItem.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());` however this not an option for me as the content of myMenuItem is created on the fly and i can end up with an empty group for example. So I will have two ToolStripSeparators without items between them.

Like this example. If `conditionA` is false or `condition1A` and `conditionA2` are false, i will get two consecutive separators.
If i move `myMenuItem.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());` inside the first or second nested if, i can get a separator inside the same group.

```
// Add group A of items
myMenuItem.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());
If(conditionA)
{
    If(conditionA1)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add("group A: item 1");
    If(conditionA2)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add("group A: item 2");
}
// Add group B of items
myMenuItem.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());
If(conditionB)
{
    If(conditionB1)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add("group B: item 1");
    If(conditionB2)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add("group B: item 2");
}
// Add group C of items
myMenuItem.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());
If(conditionC)
{
    If(conditionC1)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add("group C: item 1");
    If(conditionC2)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add("group C: item 2");
}
```

I'm wandering if there is an easy way (like tag our group option) that i can use with dynamically created items so MenuItem can decide where to put this item and whether we need a separator or not.
I know I can combine conditions or count added items so I can decide to add a separator or not, but the idea is to make the added Item it self has a decision whether to be added or not. So when initiating an Item, I can't really tell if I have to add a separator.

I'm using Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem control.

Comment: How would you end up with an empty group?  Show the code that adds the menu items.

Comment: @LarsTech i provided an example of code

Comment: No, there is no built-in method to magically add separators by default.  Any method that employs adding or inserting a separator will require you to examine the conditions or count the added items, etc.  The posted answer is one way to do it.  Don't avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest change would be to only add the separator for a group if you're going to add an item to that group:

```
// Add group A of items
If(conditionA)
{
    if(conditionA1 || conditionA2)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());
    If(conditionA1)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add("group A: item 1");
    If(conditionA2)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add("group A: item 2");
}
// Add group B of items
If(conditionB)
{
    if(conditionB1 || conditionB2)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());
    If(conditionB1)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add("group B: item 1");
    If(conditionB2)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add("group B: item 2");
}
// Add group C of items
If(conditionC)
{
    if(conditionC1 || conditionC2)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());
    If(conditionC1)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add("group C: item 1");
    If(conditionC2)
        myMenuItem.Items.Add("group C: item 2");
}
```

You could also encapsulate this into a custom control depending on how you're going to be using it.

Comment: i know i can add more if conditions or count each item added to a group, but i am asking if there is a simple way to do this so i can avoid these if statements not adding more